# What is the English word or phrase used to describe an action

Tags: phrase-request

What is the English word or phrase used to describe  who unfairly (tries to) claim, grab or receive rewards/benefits of work or efforts of others?.

Comment: Maybe you're talking about **plagiarism**?: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism More generally though, all those actions you described in your post can be easily covered by the single legal term **copyright infringement**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_infringement

Comment: @MichaelRybkin Those two are very different. Plagiarism is asserting others' intellectual work as your own without proper attribution/credit to the source (with or without the source's permission) while copyright infringement is reproducing a creative work without permission (with or without credit/attribution to the source). Posting a famous artist's song to YouTube and saying clearly who sung it is copyright infringement; paying someone else to write an essay for a course assignment that will be handed in with they payer's name is plagiarism.

Comment: Call him *boss* (pun intended!) :P

Answer (score 2):

One phrase is **to take credit for** something.

> As manager, she felt it was her right to **take all the credit** for her employee's hard work.

Answer (score 1):

Plagiary is the action of copying another person's ideas or work, without giving them credit.

This gives the verb "To plagiarise" and the agent noun "Plagiarist".

Ironically if I don't cite [Michael Rykbin](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/6450/michael-rybkin)'s answer-comment, this answer could make me a plagiarist.